# What does the Disharmony DLC add to Endless Space?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

I bought Endless Space recently in a bundle with the Disharmony DLC.

In my experience sometimes such addons are used to fix all sorts of issues and generally improve all aspects of the game. In other cases, they add extra complexity that is appreciated by experienced players but increases the learning curve for newbies.

What exactly is added by the Disharmony DLC?

Comment: Huh. This question has been edited so that a good answer to the new question (which is basically copy/pasting the wiki or the marketing) does not answer the question that I had asked. I guess the original question may have been too opinion-based for SE, although plenty on Gaming is...

Comment: I guess I should have asked "Does the Disharmony DLC steepen the learning curve for new players?", which is a little less subjective while still preserving the intent of the question. But I won't suggest that edit now, as it would make the existing answer irrelevant to the question. Just seems like a rather stupid question now, given that one could "read the box", and it has my name attached :-/

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the wiki:

1. A brand new Faction called "the Harmony" with a single objective in
   mind: Annihilate Dust!
2. New Fighter and Bomber units that will completely change the shape
   of combats, especially with the new Battle Formation and Targeting
   systems
3. A complete rework of the Ship Design interface, including an
   improved Weapon System that provides family types for modules
   (short, medium and long range)
4. New Invasion mechanics have been added: Prepare your population for
   Bombardments, Sieges and land Invasions!
5. Expect to face a real challenge when playing against AI opponents
   with the New Adaptive Multi-Agent System (AMAS)
6. Other additions and features voted or requested by the community
   include:

Five new Heroes

A new option to disable Exchange of Technologies, as a request from the Multiplayer community!

New Rally Points feature for newly built ships to reduce
    micromanagement

source: http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Endless_Space:_Disharmony

Comment: "New Rally Points feature for newly built ships to reduce micromanagement **(Not implimented)**" Too bad, this would be extremely helpful!

Comment: The "Rally Points" feature has apparently been implemented in updates since this question. Hold `Ctrl` (or platform equivalent) to enter Rally Point mode. The first click selects a star system; the second click establishes a rally destination for that star system.